# In C++, how to use template to accept arbitrary format of aggregate initialization list?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, variadic-templates, c++-templates

For instance, consider the function foo, which can be invoced as follows:

```
foo(
    {{1.0f}, 123},
    {'c', {}}
);
```

Each argument position within the function can take an aggregate initialization list ([Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)), forming a tree-like structure with arbitrary depth.

My realistic goal is to write a template constructor for an arbitrary [protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf) class. I believe this can be achieved by combining the template function mentioned previously with dynamic reflection.

Is there a solution available, or is there a reason why this cannot be accomplished?

---

Thanks for @Eljay, according to the current json libraries([nlomann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) or [taocpp](https://github.com/taocpp/json)), things can be done by using template class as template arguments of `std::initializer_list<T>`. I'll give it a try if I could figure out the black magic :'(

Comment: `{..}` has no type and can only be deduced a very few type, `std::initializer_list<T>`, C-array of `T`...

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried to combine std::tuple with variadic templates, like `std::tuple<args...>`. It can deduce `{...}` but only one layer deep. I don't know how to do this recursively.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't do it like is done in Niels Lohmann's [JSON](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)?  (Look at the `json j2` line as an example.)